# jQuery: Separate values with comma?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am aware with jQuery append method to extend something after text.

I was actually thinking about extending some special characters dynamically.

**I want-**

I have two text boxes with `display:inline`. One is for **Basic phone Number** and another is for **Mobile number**. I am getting all this information as summary after submitting with button.

I wanted to separate these two numbers with `,` separator. 
One way I could do this, By separating these with static method.

```
<input type="number" data-id="#Basic_phone#" /> , <input type="number" data-id="#Mobile_phone"/>
```

It looks like- `1234569119`,`9119119119`

But it looks bad when there is no value in database for any one input box. Then I need to type numbers, But sometimes I don't have value for one of input boxes.

then I get only (space)`,`(space) **or** `1234569119`,(space) **or** (space),`1234569119`.

I want to get comma only when both numbers are there. Sorry I don't have any idea for doing it.

Comment: Check to see if $('tag').val() > 0 before adding the ,

Answer (score 2):

Try this Demo as given [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wYrLK/)

```
function abc(){
 var str="";
 if($("#Basic_phone").val().length>0)
   str=$("#Basic_phone").val();
 if(str.length>0 && $("#Mobile_phone").val().length>0 )
   str=str+",";

str=str+$("#Mobile_phone").val()

alert(str);
}


<input type="number" id="Basic_phone" /> , <input type="number" id="Mobile_phone"/>
<input type="button" value="hello" onclick="abc()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional statements to append Comma(,), like the below one

```
     if(phoneNo != "" && mobileNo != "" ){
      //do the append code here
     }else{
        print the phone No
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating the two inputs?

If with server-side code, then just check the value before outputting the comma and second value:

```
if(Mobile_phone is not empty)
 show <input type="number" data-id="#Basic_phone#" /> , <input type="number" data-id="#Mobile_phone"/>
else
 show <input type="number" data-id="#Basic_phone#" />
```